# Boost asio getting error_code 10057 on my client chat

Tags: boost, server, client, chat, asio

I took the chat example from the boost site and I'm trying to make some modifications, but I got an error that I'm not having the slightest idea of what it can be. The server is still the same as the example, I'm working on the client, [here the original code from boost website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/chat/chat_client.cpp)

And here a little modification on the main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   try
   {
       if (argc < 4)
       {
           std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port> <keywords> [<keywords>...]\n";
           return 1;
       }
       boost::asio::io_service io_service;

       tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
       tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], argv[2]);
       tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

       chat_client c(io_service, iterator);

       boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));


       for (int i = 3; i < argc; i++)
       {

           using namespace std;
           chat_message msg;
           msg.body_length(strlen("teste"));
           memcpy(msg.body(), "teste", msg.body_length());
           msg.encode_header();
           c.write(msg);

       }
       c.close();
       t.join();
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
       std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The code looks semantically similar to the original, but I'm getting an error code 10057 in the `do_write` method when it tries an `async_write`, the error code means *"A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"*.

I'm just stuck on it, I have no idea where I'm going wrong, please can anybody point me the error?

Comment: There's no problem with the code, and it works fine for me. Check that you're running the right binary, against the right server/port etc. Are you running these on the same machine? (I notice the protocol is not portable)

Comment: Yes... man I have solved this using a sleep of 2500ms, but the reason it worked like this, I do not know. Ty for reply.

Comment: Clearly you were just failing to connect (connecting too early?). Consider handling and printing the error in `handle_connect`

Answer (score 0):

you should put c.close(); after t.join();
2. you should wait for 2~3 seconds to let io_service runing up and well.
just after boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
should Sleep(3000);

then it works